# Paypal: I'm sorry - but we were not able to process your payment. Please try another payment method or contact us so we can assist you

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, paypal-express

I'm using Magento 2 CE Version 2.1.1

Paypal Express checkout Previously Works Fine.

Now it gives below error while using Sandbox Account.

> Paypal: I'm sorry - but we were not able to process your payment.
>   Please try another payment method or contact us so we can assist you.

Comment: Have you set "Sandbox Mode" as "Yes" in admin ?

Comment: Of course Yes it is. Previously a few days ago able to do that. Suddenly it's giving an error. Not sure what happened

Comment: Suddenly it works fine now. Don't know what's issue